# How to Enable Google Analytics Enhanced eCommerce using GTM

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I had already tried to implement the configuration needed by following this video :
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IjyX6g2sZpk&ab_channel=TheSearchAgency

here is my datalayer :

```html
<script>
        var dataLayer  = window.dataLayer || [];
        dataLayer.push({
            "event": "transaction",
            "ecommerce": {
                "purchase": {
                "actionField": {
                    "id": "14c26747-503e-498c-a9b4-604fe1a479d1",
                    "affiliation": "Online Store",
                    "revenue": 41,
                    "tax": 5,
                    "shipping": 5
                },
                "products": [{
                    "id": "7w9e0",
                    "name": "Masons T-Shirt",
                    "price": "31.00",
                    "brand": "Masons",
                    "category": "T-Shirts",
                    "variant": "red",
                    "dimension1": "M",
                    "position": 0,
                    "quantity": 1
                }]
                }
            }
        });
    </script>
```

Until now i was able to receive the same datalayer in my google tag manager :
[Datalayer received in GTM Preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yy0QH.png)

and here is the config of my tag :
[GTM CONFIG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tpppC.png)

My problem is that i can't see any data in the google analytics ecommerce overview, even if i waited more than 48 hours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Check the network requests, see if you're sending your EEC data to the `?collect` endpoint.
2. Check your debugging preview, see if the EEC event has fired exactly on the event you expect it to (`transaction`)
3. Check your property/measurement id. Make sure it's the same in GA and in GTM. And in the Network tab.
4. Confirm that you're using GA UA events everywhere.

Comment: Thank you! i missed using GA UA events everywhere